# IndexedDB, I am able to access the same db on localhost with any port, just IE and Edge?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, indexeddb, same-origin-policy

Given the urls in IIS (or IISExpress)

http://localhost:5555/IndexTest.html

http://localhost:5560/IndexTest.html

I can access the same IndexDb database in both in IE 11 (windows 10) and Edge, in Chrome and Firefox the urls have their own unique dbs.

Is this correct? It's not what I was expecting. I assumed they would work like cookies, unique to the port number.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in IE/Edge. Indexed DB (like most other web stuff) uses origin as a security boundary, and origin is a tuple of (scheme, host, port) - so yes, port should matter. Special cases for localhost abound (e.g. treating it as "secure" even if it's just http) but still - sounds like a bug.

Comment: Both urls access the same website hosted in IIS, I'm assuming this doesn't make a difference.
I got a different machine (2) out and accessed the websites on pc (1) using 192.168.1.92:5555 and 192.168.1.92:5560, same effect. With two different browser windows I could add to the db in one window and see the results in another one even though they have different port numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE and Edge define the same origin policy as follows:

> Scheme and Host are the same. The port is not part of the security identifier.

**References**

- [Edge/IE same origin policy is different from RFC6454 and other browser](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2393887)
- [Same Origin Policy Part 0: Origins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/03/13/same-origin-policy-part-0-origins/)
- [Same Origin Policy Part 1: No Peeking](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/28/same-origin-policy-part-1-no-peeking/)
- [Same Origin Policy Part 2: Limited Write](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/04/02/same-origin-policy-part-2-limited-write/)
- [Client-side Cross-domain Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709423)